# ImportError raised when trying to load 'menus.templatetags.menus_tags': cannot import name 'Menus' from 'menus.models'

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am just leaning wagtail and am a bit confused now. I Have a folder structure:

site > menus > templatetags > menus_tags.py

Here is the code:

```
    from django import template

    from ..models import Menu

    register = template.Library()

    @register.simple_tag()
    def get_menu(slug):
        return Menu.objects.get(slug=slug)
```

Then in my models ( site > menus > models.py ):

```
    """Menus models"""

    from django.db import models

    from django_extensions.db.fields import AutoSlugField
    from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
    from modelcluster.models import ClusterableModel

    from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import (
        MultiFieldPanel,
        InlinePanel,
        FieldPanel, 
        PageChooserPanel
    )
    from wagtail.core.models import Orderable
    from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet

    class MenuItem(Orderable):
        
        link_title = models.CharField(
            blank=True,
            null=True,
            max_length=50
        )
        link_url = models.CharField(
            max_length=500,
            blank=True
        )
        link_page = models.ForeignKey(
            "wagtailcore.Page",
            null=True,
            blank=True,
            related_name="+",
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        )
        open_in_new_tab = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)

        page = ParentalKey("Menu", related_name="menu_items")

        panels = [
            FieldPanel("link_title"),
            FieldPanel("link_url"),
            PageChooserPanel("link_page"),
            FieldPanel("open_in_new_tab")

        ]

        # @todo add properties
        # link

        @register_snippet
        class Menu(ClusterableModel):
            """The main menu clusterable model."""

            title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
            slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from="title", editable=True)

            panels = [
                MultiFieldPanel([
                    FieldPanel("title"),
                    FieldPanel("slug"),
                ], heading="Menu"),
                InlinePanel("menu_items", label="Menu Item")
            ]

            def __str__(self):
                return self.title
```

Now when I compile I am now getting the above import error. I am sure that the paths are correct but I have no idea why it can import menus from the model. ANy help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `class Menu` definition is indented, so it appears inside the definition of `class MenuItem` - this means it is not visible as a class inside the `models` module. Remove this indent and it should work.